# Does the set of power sets exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that you’re given a collection of sets. Now, for each set of this collection, its power set exists by Axiom of Power Sets. But can we also guarantee the existence of the *collection* of those power sets?

Answer (score 2):

By the axiom of replacement, if the original collection of sets is a set, the collection of power sets is a set.

In general, however, no. For instance, the collection of power sets of all ordinals isn't a set.

Comment: Does "collection" have an agreed upon meaning? Is it different from class?

Comment: @idlemathematician I’m following Halmos here. So a collection is a set.

Comment: @idlemathematician Classes are defined by a formula their elements satisfy. The intuitive, naïve notion of collection could plausibly be even wider, although it, in that case, would be difficult to give it a rigorous meaning. In the end, however, it matters little, as this answer remains the same.

Comment: @Arthur Can you show that from Axiom of Specification? Since I’ve never heard of Replacement.

Comment: @Atom No, not really. Specification / comprehension deals with subsets and restrictions of things that are already sets. Here we are asking about a construction where we put together sets to make something larger, and specification doesn't touch that at all. Union, pairing, power set and replacement are the axioms that go in that direction.

Comment: @Arthur But Halmos doesn’t mention of it before giving as an exercise to prove that intersection of power sets of the sets of a collection is equal to the power set of the intersection of the collection.

Comment: @Arthur The LHS of this is not even defined! All he states prior to this are: axioms of extension, specification, pairs, unions and powers, with a tentative axiom that there is a set.

Comment: @Atom Intersections is an entirely different story! That's specification all the way. You can start with one of the power sets, and then specify "all the elements of this power set which is also a subset of all the other sets". No need to have available the collection of power sets.

Comment: @Arthur Yes! That’s it! But only for intersections. Halmos also asks to prove that for the case of *unions*, it will become an inclusion. What to do here?

Comment: @Atom Hmm... There I can't see a way to avoid replacement to define what you've called the LHS. Otherwise you don't have a set of power sets to take union over. There may be some tricky trick to it, but it is beyond me at the moment.

Comment: Avoiding replacement is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it was a set, $S$, then $\mathcal P(S)$ was an element of $S$, this alone contradicts the axiom of regularity: $S\in\mathcal P(S)\in S$ means that $\{S,\mathcal P(S)\}$ is a set without a minimal element.

But we can do better. By the axiom of union, $\bigcup S$ is a set. But since *every* set has a power set, and of course *every* set is an element of its own power set. This means that $\bigcup S$ is a set which contains all sets, and now using separation we have that $\{x\in\bigcup S\mid x\text{ is a set}\}$ is the set of all sets, which itself is impossible by Russell's paradox.

(Note: if you already work in a case where all objects are sets, you can omit the use of separation, since $\bigcup S$ is already the set of all sets.)